# Marginal PDFs and conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Consider the set
    \begin{align*}
    E=\{(x,y) \mid |x| + |y| \le 1\}.
\end{align*}
    Suppose that we choose a point $(X,Y)$ uniformly at random in $E$. That is, the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
    \begin{align*}
    f_{XY}(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
        c & (x,y)\in E \\
        0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

I let $A$ be the area of $E$. I know that

\begin{align*}
1&=\iint \limits_{E} f_{XY}(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= c\iint \limits_{E} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&=cA.
\end{align*}

$E$ forms a square with the side length $l=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$, so $A=l^2=2$ og therefore

\begin{align*}
1&=2c \Rightarrow c=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

**Determine marginal PDFs**

I see that $R_X=R_Y=[-1,1]$. I know that for all $x$ that
\begin{align*}
f_X(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_{XY}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}

Integration limits:
\begin{align*}
|x|+|y|\le 1 &\Rightarrow |y| \le 1-|x| \\
&\Rightarrow |x|-1 \le y \le 1-|x|.
\end{align*}
So for $(x,y) \in E$, I get that
\begin{align*}
f_X(x)&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|} \mathrm{d}y \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-|x|-(|x|-1)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(2-2|x|\right) \\
&=1-|x|.
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        1-|x| & (x,y)\in E \\
        0 & \mathrm{ellers}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Likewise I know that:
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_{XY}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
But since $E$ er symmetrical, I conclude that
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)=
    \begin{cases}
        1-|y| & (x,y)\in E \\
        0 & \mathrm{ellers}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

**Determine $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$**

I know that
\begin{align*}
f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)&=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} \\
&=\frac{1}{2(1-|y|}.
\end{align*}

From the above I see that $f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)$ is not defined for $|y|=1$. So I want to split up into cases. The above result is valid for $|y| < 1$. When $|y|=1$ then $P(X=0 \mid Y=1)=1$ so $X \mid Y$ is a discrete random variable with $R_{X\mid Y}=\{0\}$.

**That's as far as I've got here, how do I proceed?**

**Check if $X$ and $Y$ are independent**

If $X$ og $Y$ are independent, then
\begin{align*}
f_{XY}(x,y)&=f_X(x)f_Y(y) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}&=(1-|x|)(1-|y|) \\
&=1-|y|-|x|+|x||y|
\end{align*}

**That is as far as I've got here, how do I proceed?**

I would also like to draw  $x \mapsto f_X(x)$ and $x \mapsto f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y)$ and see where there is highest probability for $X$ and $X \mid Y = y$.

**How do I draw $x \mapsto f_{X \mid Y} (x \mid y)$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

You conclude that $f_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1-\left|x\right| & \text{if }\left(x,y\right)\in E\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Note however that $f_{X}$ is a function with only one argument. It
would be correct to state that: $$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1-\left|x\right| & \text{if }\left|x\right|<1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

A similar story for $f_{Y}$.

Working out $f_{X\mid Y}\left(x\mid y\right)=\frac{f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)}{f_{Y}\left(y\right)}$
must take place in the awareness that $y$ is a fixed number with
$\left|y\right|<1$ which in this context leads to: $$f_{X\mid Y}\left(x\mid y\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\left(1-\left|y\right|\right)} & \text{if }\left|y\right|-1<x<1-\left|y\right|\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This makes clear how to draw the function prescribed by $x\mapsto f_{X\mid Y}\left(x\mid y\right)$
for a fixed $\left|y\right|<1$. In the case where $\left|y\right|\geq1$
the function is not defined and in the case where $\left|y\right|<1$
it takes two distinct values.

From the fact that $y$ is present in the expression it may be concluded
that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

The case $\left|Y\right|=1$ is irrelevant because $P\left(\left|Y\right|=1\right)=0$
so that conditional probabilities like $P\left(X\in B\mid Y=1\right)$
and $P\left(X\in B\mid Y=-1\right)$ are not well defined.

It is not
correct to state that $\left(X\mid Y\right)$ is a discrete random
variable under $Y=1$.

Actually $\left(X\mid Y=y\right)$ does not even
denote a random variable but only a distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following all your concerns, since you seem to have things more or less as might be expected, and/or I'm misunderstanding what is being asked, but here are a few thoughts that hopefully might help.

In regards to the independence, perhaps you can show that the equality is not satisfied for particular values of $x$ and $y$, say $x=1/4$ and $y=1/4$.  The right hand side would give you $1-1/4-1/4+1/16 \ne 1/2$, therefore the random variables are not independent.

In regards to drawing the functions, it might be useful to start with the basic domain of the valid values of $x$ and $y$ which, I believe, can be described as a rotated square in the x-y plane-looking down from z-direction:

```
                            y                         f_xy(x|y)
                            |                             |      
                            |                        -----|----- h
                           .|.                       |    |    |
                         .  |  .                     |    |    |
  y=k (fixed)  --------.----|----.-----    -->    ----------------x
                     .      |      .               -(1-k)     1-k
               ----.-----------------.-----x          
                     .      |      . 
                       .    |    .                    h=1/(2*(1-|k|))
                         .  |  .
                           .|.
                            |
                            |
```

The conditional functions $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ would be cuts in the horizontal direction, with constant height and limited x range.
Perhaps this suggests some directions.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I already drew $E$ itself. Could you elaborate on the drawing of $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$? Also, I'm in doubt about how to think about where there is highest probability for $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I added some more information to the drawing which hopefully will help.